# Graphic generation becomes slow in Java

Tags: java, android, graphics

I'm trying to figure out how a good way to create a hex tiled enviroment to build a game upon and I'm not sure this is the right place for this kind of question so gently ask me to remove this if I'm at the wrong place.

I have created a skeleton of a way to handle and generate a map but I don't have to make the map especially big before it takes quite a while to load it so maybe you guys could help me find what I have made stupid.

I'm guess that there is redundant code in the class resourceStorage but I don't know much about image handling.

Also, is what I have build here a dead end? Should I do this with JavaFX or some library of some kind? (I want it to work on android)

http://pastebin.com/gWXcyPHP

public class WorldView extends Canvas
{
    private Map map;

```
//Graphics related
private BufferStrategy buffer;
private int scale;

public WorldView(Map map, int scale)
{
    this.map = map;
    this.scale = 35;

    JFrame container = new JFrame("Stroll");
    container.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)container.getContentPane();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    this.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    panel.add(this);

    this.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    container.pack();
    container.setResizable(false);
    container.setVisible(true);

    this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    buffer = getBufferStrategy();

    refreshWindow();
}

public void refreshWindow()
{
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    for (Map.Entry<HexPoint, Tile> entry: map.entrySet())
    {
        Point pixelPoint = calcCoordsToPixels(entry.getKey(), scale);
        entry.getValue().draw(g, pixelPoint.x, pixelPoint.y, scale);
    }

    g.dispose();
    buffer.show();
}
```

}

public class Tile
{
    private Terrain terrain;

```
//Graphics
private int scale = 0;
private BufferedImage image;
private boolean needsRepaint;

public Tile(Terrain terrain)
{
    this.terrain = terrain;
    needsRepaint = true;
}

public void draw(Graphics g, int x, int y, int scale)
{
    if (this.scale != scale)
    {
        image = ResourceStore.get().getImage(terrain, scale);
        this.scale = scale;
        needsRepaint = true;
    }
    if (needsRepaint)
    {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
        needsRepaint = false;
    }

    //also calls other objects who resides on this tile for repainting
}
```

}

public class ResourceStore
{

```
private static ResourceStore single = new ResourceStore();
private int scale = 0;

public static ResourceStore get()
{
    return single;
}

private HashMap<Terrain, BufferedImage> images = new HashMap();

public BufferedImage getImage(Terrain terrain, int scale)
{
    if (images.get(terrain) != null && this.scale == scale)
    {
        return images.get(terrain);
    }

    if (images.get(terrain) != null)
    {
        return resize(images.get(terrain), scale, false);
    }

    BufferedImage sourceImage = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main/resources/" + terrain.getName());

        if (url == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't load image");
        }

        sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Can't load image");
    }

    sourceImage = resize(sourceImage, scale, false);

    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), Transparency.BITMASK);

    image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);

    images.put(terrain, image);
    return image;
}

public BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int scale, boolean transparent)
{
    int width = scale * 2;
    int height = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * width);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT); //maybe change?
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    if (!transparent)
    {
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
    } else
    {
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Composite comp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, (float) 0.5);
        g2d.setComposite(comp);
    }
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post relevant code here, don't link to it.

Comment: If you are planning on doing a game in java, i am afraid that the core libraries may not be enough for creating a game, you can use the java graphics library but I wouldn't recommend it as it's support is very limited,  I suggest you using a library that is intended for that purpose, there are a lot of good ones out there depending on what game you're making, I suggest you start using an all purpose one like lwjgl (note: I suggest not to start with lwjgl 3 as it is WIP and hardly has any tutorials except some sample code) and if you are into game engines and 3D you can go for JMonkey engine.